# .Net Core get Objects of ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've added a few specific Properties to the ApplicationUser of the standart project.
some of the added Properties are of custom classes.
Since i use EntityFramework, it creates a dbtable for users and one for each custom class.
i added the Properties to my ManageController and Views and adding these Properties to the specific dbtable works, but i cant access them. in the dbo.AspNetUsers there is a column added, that is called after the attribute + ID (In my example "NameID").

Now if i am loading the user in my ManageController, every normal Attribute is loaded, but the custom ones are null.

My Question is, how can i load the custom objects (that are really stored in the other table).

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
namespace refProject.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ManageController.cs

```
//other usings
using refProject.Models;
using refProject.Models.ManageViewModels;

namespace refProject.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ManageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        //other managers

        public ManageController(
          UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
          //other managers
          )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            //other managers
        }

        //
        // GET: /Manage/Index
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message = null)
        {
            ViewData["StatusMessage"] =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangeNameSuccess ? "Your name has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetNameSuccess ? "Your name has been set."
                : "";

            var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
            if (user == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var model = new IndexViewModel
            {
                //other Properties
                //
                //
                // THIS ONE IS NULL
                //
                //        
                Name = user.Name
                //other Properties
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: /Manage/ChangeName
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ChangeName()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Manage/ChangeName
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeName(ChangeNameViewModel model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
            if(user != null)
            {
                Name NewName = new Name();
                NewName.FirstName = model.NewFirstName;
                NewName.LastName = model.NewLastName;

                user.Name = NewName;

                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeNameSuccess });
                }
                AddErrors(result);
                return View(model);
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Manage/SetName
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SetName()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Manage/SetName
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SetName(SetNameViewModel model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
            if(user != null)
            {
                Name NewName = new Name();
                NewName.FirstName = model.NewFirstName;
                NewName.LastName = model.NewLastName;

                user.Name = NewName;

                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if(result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetNameSuccess });
                }
                AddErrors(result);
                return View(model);
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        #region Helpers

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            Error,
            ChangeNameSuccess,
            SetNameSuccess,
        }

        private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
        {
            return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Name.cs

```
namespace refProject.Models
{
    public class Name
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string fTitle { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string lTitle { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return fTitle + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + lTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using non-standard terms. Attributes = Properties?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a known issue. It is not considered a bug, but rather a design decision.

The recommended way is to access the user through `DbContext` rather than from the `UserManager` implementation.

> "Just to add a bit more detail: as a performance optimization ASP.NET Core Identity currently only loads the entities related to a user or a role as needed to satisfy API calls. I.e. it won't load related entities (not even the built-in ones) eagerly on a method call like such as `FindByName()` because the find methods are only required to return the root.
>
> At this point issuing queries against the `DbContext` is the recommended
>   way to load related data. If you want to abstract this from the
>   application code you can extend both the Identity store and manager
>   classes to add methods to retrieve and return your custom related
>   data."
>
> [Comment link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/724#issuecomment-175921945)

You could change your `GetCurrentUserAsync` method as follows:

```
private ApplicationUser GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
    return _userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _userManager.GetUserId(User));
}
```